# Pandas: df.iterrows for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't unterstand what the number in brackets means after line.

```
for line in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[line[0],'color'] = get_color(wavelenght)
    print(df)
```

The code is producing my data frame as I wish but I want to understand what the number there means.

Comment: Try printing `line[0]` to see what it is

Comment: In thise case, `iterrows()` returns a tuple with values `index, row`. The `line[0]` is accessing the first element of the tuple, which is the index.

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) does

> Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs.

You are storing subsequent pairs in variable named `line`, `line[0]` denotes first element (index), `line[1]` would denote second element (series)